# Cookie per browser instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, cookies

We have a ASP.Net system, when the user logs in he gets a cookie that includes the user name.

This works fine, when there is a single user using the machine.

Where we have problems is when a user is testing the system having many browsers open and logging in with many id's.

In this case all browser instances will be logged in with the last user to log in.

Is there are way to be logged in with different users to different browser instances / tabs.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think this is down to browser behaviour rather than anything that you can do. Maybe have a search for browsers that have that behaviour, or as a last-ditch you could make a simple browser for yourself. Otherwise maybe set up virtual machines so that 1 computer has more than 1 virtual computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this as long as each browser is different.

It won't work if you open 4 copies of IE, but it will work if you open one copy of IE, one of Firefox, one of Chrome, one of Safari. Cookies are saved per browser, not per browser window.

Comment: He knows this, he's asking about varying sessions between **instances** of browsers